# How can I create ActorSelection from ActorContext[T]

Tags: akka

In the time since my last Akka project, Akka has moved on to a more cluster oriented approach.

I like the patterns that akka.actor.typed provide.   But I am not building a clustered system.  I looked at clustering, but I think my system is too fragmented and more static than a system that would make a reasonable cluster.

I have the bones of a system but I can't form bonds because I can't crate ActorSelections to connect my nodes.   I have poked around in akka.actor.typed and don't see a path to creating an ActorSelection.

Is there a way to create an ActorSelection from anything I have access to in akka.actor.typed?

Is there another way to obtain an address to a remote actor system at a known port?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I see you figured out how to fall back to the classic APIs however I'd recommend that you read up on the typed receptionist for discovering actors instead of falling back to string lookups like that as they are more brittle and gives quite a tight coupling.

The receptionist works both in a single ActorSystem and in a cluster without changes. With the receptionist an actor that wants to provide a service registers itself using a typed key. Actors wanting to interact with it can subscribe or lookup available actors through the key (or use a group router which will keep track of available actors for a key and route to them).

See docs https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/typed/actor-discovery.html#receptionist and https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/typed/routers.html#group-router

Comment: I did look at that a bit but it didn't jump out to me how that would allow disparate actor systems to connect. If you specify the port of the receptionist and outsides call it that could work.  ActorSelection is a pain and the factory doesn't name the actors with the old rules so you have to look at it.  I'll take another look, thanks!

Comment: It will only work with actors inside the same cluster, not over separate systems over remoting (which we recommend you avoid doing anyway, see callout up top here https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/remoting-artery.html#artery-remoting )

Comment: I would love to be able to work on real world type applications, but I really don't live that world.   All of the cluster stuff makes good sense and I might be able to shoehorn what I am doing into it.  I am writing a library that is very like a cluster, and  you all have much more experience with that than I.

Comment: There are issues, we only have one machine in a role (real machines not farms), and it is unlikely that all machines can talk directly.  \n\n In a tightly coupled project the ability to pass around case classes is fantastic, don't throw out that baby.

Comment: Can nodes that have joined a cluster then be used by other nodes to join?  My clusters mostly would touch edges.  Some may have a gateway between.

Answer (score 0):

After more digging I found the answer in the the Akka doc.
https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/typed/coexisting.html

```
import akka.actor.typed.scaladsl.adapter._

val context: ActorContext[t]

context.toClassic.actorSelection("akka://actorSystemName@10.0.0.1:25520/user/actorName")
```